# Search page with cascading fields

Tags: 2013, search, column, spservices, cascading

we would like to build a search page which is searching publishing pages in SP2013. The search should look for values in three metadata columns. But the search dialog should be cascaded (first choose value of field_1 and choice of field_2 depends on field_1 etc.)

[spservices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/documentation) delivers such functionality but this seems to be constructed for listforms. Possible use for a search page?

Is client-side coding the best approach or better develop custom webpart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this very easily with the Client Side Object Model and JavaScript. You can write it as a Web part or as an App (add-in, etc.) Use the Search REST API to supply a keyword query specifying your managed properties and the values. Since you mention Publishing Pages, you may want to create a Result Source for your Publishing Pages to narrow the results initially.

Comment: thanks Matthew, sounds good, I'll try this even though creating result sources and search result presenting don't belong to my every day tasks ;-)